# How to read a Data Matrix barcode

Tags: java, itext, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I have to read a  Data Matrix code inside of a PDF file, I was investigating the posibilities, and I had some questions about that:

1.- I work with Itext, I was looking for information about the posibility to read this QR barcode with this library, but I have not results about that, is possible??

2.- I discovered another library ZXING : https://github.com/zxing/zxing, but I could not find the way to read inside the PDF.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

---

New Information, with new Ideas, for fix the problem:

This is my code, with PDFBOX I find the image for each page, afterwards I check if is this image is a barcode for get the data, I don't know why but I can't detect a barcode with this code, the quality of the barcode is high in the PDF.

I try to use the Reader implementation but I couldn't find it, I have the version 3.1 ZXING, perhaps is in another version?

If I use directly the image from the file like this, works perfect:

> Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\Workarea\testBarcode.png"));
>   BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;

```
PDDocument document; try {
    document3 = PDDocument.load("TEST_QR_BARCODE.pdf");
    List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

    Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
    while( iter.hasNext() )
    {
        PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();
        PDResources resources = page.getResources();
        Map images;

            images = resources.getImages();

        if( images != null )
        {
            Iterator imageIter = images.keySet().iterator();
            while( imageIter.hasNext() )
            {
                String key = (String)imageIter.next();
                PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)images.get( key );
                BufferedImage testcojones = image.getRGBImage();

                try {
                    LuminanceSource source;

                    source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(testcojones);

                    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

                    Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);

                    ParsedResult parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result);

                    System.out.println(" (format: " + result.getBarcodeFormat() + ", type: " +
                    parsedResult.getType() + "):\nRaw result:\n" + result.getText() + "\nParsed result:\n" +
                    parsedResult.getDisplayResult());
                    System.out.println("Found " + result.getResultPoints().length + " result points.");

                    for (int i = 0; i < result.getResultPoints().length; i++) {
                        ResultPoint rp = result.getResultPoints()[i];
                        if (rp != null) {
                            System.out.println(" Point " + i + ": (" + rp.getX() + ',' + rp.getY() + ')');
                        }
                    }

                    } catch (NotFoundException ignored) {
                        System.out.println("No barcode found!");
                    }

            }
        }
    } } catch (IOException e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e2.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: Hi, @JOANA_Batista . Am also looking to find a way to read the barcode using PDFBox. Were you able to find any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use zxing, you just need to create a `BufferedImage` in your Java program from the PDF. That's a separate question, but should be possible with another library. Then you can use `BufferedImageLuminanceSource` in mostly the way you see done here: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/javase/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/DecodeWorker.java#L125

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean Owen for your answer :D, I going to try first to convert my PDF in BufferedImage with PDFBOX library, then I can test if works with ZXING my QR barcode, I will come back to you for post the solution for help another people with your fantastic Library :)

Comment: There is also a `Reader` implementation that can look for several QR codes at once.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information, I tryed yesterday, and I could transform PDF to BufferedImage with PDFBOX, but when I use BufferedImageLuminanceSource to search the QR barcode, I had not results, But I think the problem comes from the conversion, I had a lot of warnings with PDFBOX, today I have another strategy more efficient, the idea is take the QR barcode directly with ITEXT like a image, transform the object PDXObjectImage to BufferedImage, along the day I will comment my progress. thanks for your help again

Comment: Sean Owen I don't Know exactlly why? but I have a problem when I got my object BufferedImage, I triyed from Itext and PDFFBOX I can't find the Barcode, but if I take directly from the file, like a .png works perfect, whats is wrong?

Comment: Now works, but only if my BufferedImage have a #pixelBits = 8 if have 1 doesn't work, exist some way to fix that without touch the QR barcode?